# custom svg not displaying properly in fluttericon

Tags: flutter, adobe-illustrator

I am trying to create custom icons (so svgs) in Adobe Illustrator for flutter so I am trying to load svg files into fluttericon. However, once I upload the svg file to fluttericon it only shows an outline and the actual symbol is not showing.
[image]

In Illustrator, I tried to Saves as SVG, Export as SVG and Exports for Screens -> SVG but none of them seem to work.

Am I missing something? If I upload another svg I got online it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Does it work correctly when you paste the xml codes here? -> https://www.svgviewer.dev/

Comment: yes, it works as intended. It also works when I open it in Photoshop

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out: In Illustrator, you need to turn the shapes into a compound path first and then export as svg (Object -> Compound path -> make). That way it shows up fine in fluttericon.

fluttericon has a good explanation for that as well: https://github.com/fontello/fontello/wiki/How-to-use-custom-images#importing-svg-images

Comment: Is there another way to fix this without using Illustrator?